# Given a list of numbers L and a target k, is there a subset of numbers from L whose product is k?

Tags: dynamic-programming, np, decision-problem

Is there any dynamic way of solving this problem? I would thank any help, I know the Subset sum Problem, but for solving it dynamically u have to create a matrix but here is not posible as the colums may not to be integers.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 0):

It’s a nice problem.

If all numbers were given factored into products of prime powers, say 2^2*3^2 instead of 36, or 2^3835857109 instead of a billion digit number then the problem would be NP complete - restricting all numbers to be powers of two would produce the subset sum problem if we just look at the exponents. But writing the numbers as decimal numbers blows up the problem size. I don’t think the subset sum problem with limited size of numbers is NP-complete. (I may be wrong, anything about that would be appreciated).

It seems obvious to factor the numbers. But if we have a 100 digit number which might be a 100 digit prime or the product of two 50 digit numbers, that is hard.

But whether x is prime or the product of two large primes may be irrelevant. What we do: We pick any 2 numbers x, y in the problem and calculate g = gcd (x, y), and if g is not 1 then we replace x by g * (x/ g) and y by g * (y/g), until all pairs of numbers are examined and all gcds are > 1. This is easily done in polynomial time. If a large x could be a product p*q, but no other number has a factor p or q, then it is irrelevant whether x is prime or not. And while factoring 100 digit numbers is hard, calculating the gcd is easily done in quadratic time in the number of bits of the numbers, much smaller than the actual numbers.

So now we write each $L_i$ and the target $k$ as products of $x_j^{e_j}$, and we need a subset of the $L_i$ so that for every $j$, the sum of exponents of $x_j$ for the subset of $L_i$ matches the sum of exponents in $k$. The problem is NP-complete but only because we decreased it's size massively.

First step we throw out all numbers that don't divide k (have a factor $x_i$ that is not a factor of k, or a factor raised to a higher power). Then for every $x_j$, we count the exponents: If the members of $L_i$ have a smaller sum of exponents than k, then there is no solution. If they have exactly the same sum, then the solution contains all numbers with a factor $x_j$ (and others); we check that their product divides k. If not there is no solution. If yes, the solution includes those $x_j$, so we write this down, then remove them from L, and divide k by their product.

There may be other cases where we can determine a solution, for example if we have three numbers with factors $x^2$, $x^3$ and $x^4$ and k has a factor $x^1$ to $x^9$ then each factor can be produced in exactly one way or not at all. And every time we have found a part of the solution, we may continue and find more parts that were not there before. And every time we reduce k, some $L_i$ might not divide k anymore and can be removed.

You can come up with more complicated rules that force a part of the solution. At some point you are finished and have to go to backtracking. You take one $x_j$ and assume it's part of the solution. Then you remove it from the problem, dividing k by $x_j$, and try to solve the remaining problem. You find a solution, or you try another $x_j$. For example, if k has a factor $x^1$ then your solution must contain exactly one number with a factor $x^1$ so that is what you try.